# “was unexpected at this time.”

Tags: windows, postgresql, cmd

I'm trying to run the following code but is encountering the "was unexpected at this time" error.

> (echo COPY (SELECT ta.colA as name, ta.colB as user_e, ta.colC as user_n, ta.activation_dt, ta.creation_dt, MAX(tb.update_dt) as updated_at, MAX(tb.login_dt) as lastest_login, tc.colD as roleFROM tblA ta, tblB tb, tblC tc WHERE ta.id = tb.tb_id AND ta.tc_id = tc.id AND tc.colD <> 'Guest' GROUP BY ta.colA, ta.colB, ta.colC, ta.activation_dt, ta.creation_dt, tc.colD ORDER BY ta.colA, tc.colD^^^) TO 'E:\Details.csv' CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER;) | psql -h localhost -p 8060 -U uname -d dbase

Looking for some insights please. Thank you.

[Screenshot of error encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtwAG.png)

Comment: Do you enter this into the shell or `psql`? Can you copy and paste the actual error message?

Comment: I am trying to run this via batch file. "was unexpected at this time.” was the only message I encounter when I try to run the batch file. Although, when I run this code via PSQL Console (pgAdmin III), it completes successfully without errors.

Comment: It didn't tell you *what* was unexpected at this time? This error message does not come from PostgreSQL. Can you specify *how exactly* you go about "running a batch file"?

Comment: That's a Windows error message, not a Postgres error message. You need to escape the `<` and `>` otherwise Windows will use them as a redirection sign. And the `^^^` looks incorrect as well.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, I have include in this post the error message I am encountering and also on how I ran the batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding some quotes around the SQL, and lose the brackets:

```
echo "COPY ..." | psql -h localhost -p 8060 -U uname -d dbase
```

or use `-c` option:

> `psql -h localhost -p 8060 -U uname -d dbase -c "COPY ..."`

I prefer the `-c` because it works on all OS

Comment: Thank you for this. I have used the 2nd option and made some tweaks with my code and it ran successfully.